# Install ruby on rails on centOS

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, centos, redmine

These days ,I try to install Redmine (a web app based on ruby on rails) on centOS.
I followed the offical guide on ruby website.However I met a problem:
in the terminate:

```
[root@localhost aaa]# cd blog 
[root@localhost blog]# rails -v
Rails 3.2.6

    [root@localhost blog]# rails server
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 3.2.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    => Call with -d to detach
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    [2012-07-03 07:01:32] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    [2012-07-03 07:01:32] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2012-06-29) [i686-linux]
    [2012-07-03 07:01:32] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=20517 port=3000
    ...
```

it works well.
However when I start another app Redmine.

```
[root@localhost aaa]# cd redmine
[root@localhost redmine]# rails -v
script/rails:6:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/commands (LoadError)
        from script/rails:6
[root@localhost redmine]# rails server
script/rails:6:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/commands (LoadError)
        from script/rails:6
...
```

The result makes me confused.Any one can help me.

Comment: Have you run bundle yet?

Comment: l have run 'bundle install',but it seems do  not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like redmine is rails 2.x and blog is rails 3.x. I've solved this problem using RVM & gemsets. You can search for other ways to run multiple versions of rails.